# No Longer Grinchy. Как её получить, имея менее 3к репутации?

Tags: поддержка, новогодние-шляпы

Я знаю описание

> participate in successfully reopening or undeleting a question

Могу ли я получить данную шляпу, имея менее 3к репутации? И что это за "undelete", можно вернуть удалённый вопрос? Сколько надо иметь репутации для этого?

Comment: Тоже думаю, что никак. Доступ к "Голоса за повторное открытие" от 3к репутации.

Comment: _И что это за "undelete", можно вернуть удалённый вопрос? Сколько надо иметь репутации для этого?_ - [_Можно если они не были удалены модератором, 20000+_](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте удалить и восстановить собственный вопрос. ;)

Comment: Пффф!! Неужели сработает? Это гипотеза или есть уверенность?

Comment: @AK а вы проверьте)

Comment: @NickVolynkin Либо это просто не работает, либо ответ неполный и там есть какие-то ещё нюансы.

Comment: Попробовал на новом вопросе. Создал вопрос, удалил, нажал "редактировать", не пустило ("нет такого вопроса"), окей - нажал восстановить, восстановил, подредактировал (уже порядок нарушен на шапку), получил плюс один в ответ. Шапку не начислили. У @VadimOvchinnikov видимо то же самое.